# Error with pfx certificate "The specified network password is not correct."

Tags: api, ssl, encryption, pfx

I am trying to run a console application that accesses an API using a pfx certificate and I am getting the following error.

> 2022-03-21 11:25:22.0244 - ERROR: Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper+WindowsCryptographicException: The specified network password is not correct.
> at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.FilterPFXStore(ReadOnlySpan'1 rawData, SafePasswordHandle password, PfxCertStoreFlags pfxCertStoreFlags)
> at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.FromBlobOrFile(ReadOnlySpan'1 rawData, String fileName, SafePasswordHandle password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
> at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate..ctor(String fileName, String password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
> at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor(String fileName, String password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
> at ADP_API.APICall.GetHttpClientHandler() in E:\repos\ADP_API\ADP_API\APICall.cs:line 315
> at ADP_API.APICall.Authenticate() in E:\repos\ADP_API\ADP_API\APICall.cs:line 79

Running the application works on my local machine and my co worker's machine. The pfx file was created with no password therefore doesn't require one. When we try to run it on a server running Windows Server 2012 it says the specific network password is not correct.

I tried installing the certificate on the server and when I try to continue from the window that asks for a password, it responds with "The password you entered is incorrect.". I tried installing it on my local machine again and it allows me to pass through the password window with no password.

I tried adding the .key and .pem files in the same folder as the pfx file and no luck with that either.

Comment: Are you running this as a real user? Or is it IIS/windows service? is ssl hardening installed?

Comment: There are different was to generate the encryption key from the entered password and the used encryption algorithm. Windows 2012 is outdated and only support some old algorithm (TripleDES_SHA1) to do so. Therefore it will fail to open a PFX file that was generated using a program that uses the new key generation (AES256_SHA256) algorithm. SO the correct error would be "unknown algorithm" but Windows just shows "The password you entered is incorrect."

Comment: I had the same issue with server 2012, I ended up converting the pfx file to a pem file and then loaded it like this `IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("path_to_some.pem")),` then adding the Bearers Token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We tried installing the certificate on one of our servers with Windows Server 2019 and it worked. After we tried this I saw Robert's comment above and it appears he is correct. Thank you Robert.

Windows 2012 is outdated and won't work for a PFX file. Solution is going to a newer Windows Server.

Comment: Or use openssl 1.1.1 (not 3)

Comment: This is the command that I ran for open SSL that works for Windows Server 2012 R2 (Notice the -certpbe and the -keypbe flags)

openssl pkcs12 -export -certpbe PBE-SHA1-3DES -keypbe PBE-SHA1-3DES -nomac -out OUTPUT_FILE.pfx -inkey KEY_FILE.key -in CERTIFICATE.crt -certfile INTERMEDIATE.pem

Answer (score 3):

This is not really an answer but I would like to highlight the comment from https://stackoverflow.com/users/2152973/fran%c3%a7ois-breton that led to fix my problem.

Using a recent version of **openssl 1.1.1** made it work.

I was having this issue with a `.pfx` file made in *Ubuntu* with **openssl 3.0.2** that was not being accepted in Azure.